# How to convert base64 wav to base64 mp3 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, base64, mp3

I have a trouble in my app.

I want to record a sound and store it in iOS using Cordova. I have already a base64/wav file, but it's very heavy so I want to convert it into a base64/mp3.

Which is the algorithm that allows me to do that?

Example:

```
b64Wavtob64mp3("base64/...");
// Return a mp3 base64
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676396/convert-wav-to-mp3-using-javascript

You can use Recordmp3js.

Comment: Sorry artex, but I am asking for Cordova, I have implemented that solution in the browser, but at devices it does not work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Goyuso, you've found the solution already? Thanks

Comment: Hi @bagusflyer, you can see my solution right here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I forgot completely `base64` because I was looking for a audio compressed***

Solved!

I did it with a `wav2m4a` plugin.

> https://github.com/xu-li/phonegap-wav2m4a

But I wanted to go further so I modified `CDVSound.m` at iOS.
I just followed these instructions:

> https://gist.github.com/jlsuarezs/d48094d431307a466496

1. Add to the `startRecordingAudio` method on `CDVSound.m` this:

   NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                       nil];
2. Replace:

   audioFile.recorder = [[CDVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:audioFile.resourceURL settings:nil error:&error]; // Default PCM recording

   With:

   audioFile.recorder = [[CDVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:audioFile.resourceURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];

   3. Changing another lines:
      CDVSound.m checks to make sure you're using a wav file. Simply changing this at the top of the file should prevent that.

   ## define RECORDING_WAV @"wav"

I changed it to:

```
#define RECORDING_WAV @"m4a"
```

or

```
#define RECORDING_M4A @"m4a"
```

and change in the file instances that contains the `RECORDING_WAV` variable.