# How to convert .wav base64 to .mp3 base64 using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have .wav base64 file but its not working in IE since IE supports only mp3 files.
So how can I convert .wav base64 to .mp3 base64 use pure **JavaScript** only, so that I can use it in IE

Comment: Or suggest me how can I use .wav base64 audio file in IE?

Comment: This really isn't a programming related question...

Comment: I want to use audio tag of HTML5 in IE but my source file is in base64 wav format. How can I use this file because IE supports only mp3 file

Comment: I think it's possible to read .wav in IE (if recent versions I guess, like 10/11), see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762763/play-wav-sound-file-encoded-in-base64-with-javascript and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

Comment: No IE is not supporting wav format file..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert base64 wav to base64 mp3 in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532265/how-to-convert-base64-wav-to-base64-mp3-in-javascript)

Comment: @MoshFeu this question is about Cordova, which uses some device native methods, won't work on desktop

Comment: @Rohit, you will need an external library to do so, found [this one](https://github.com/ffdead/wav.js/blob/master/README.md) but never tried it. Also, a better approach would be to convert it first to mp3 or some supported format, not in front-end

Comment: @Kaiido you are right. My mistake..