# How to play 13kbps .wav file in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I have to play a 13kbps .wav file on my browser and none of the browsers seem to support it. I heard we can covert it to a higher bit rate, preferably 128kbps .wav file or to a .mp3 format. How do I convert it to mp3 or higher bit rate wav file using javascript.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible with JS, but I'll be damned it is possible. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23682012/2813224) And if it helped you please upvote rafaelcastrocouto's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert wav to mp3 using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676396/convert-wav-to-mp3-using-javascript)

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto- I did upload a wav audio file and it worked. But when I tried to upload a 13kbps wav file it did not play the file. Is it my browsers' issue? I use Chrome.