# Convert .amr Base64 string to Mp3 file

Tags: javascript, cordova, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to convert any audio type base64 string to Mp3 file, I have base64 string with AMR and WAV format which is recorded,I need to convert it in Mp3 format and save it in server.If any one has done this or any example would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676396/convert-wav-to-mp3-using-javascript

Comment: @its use to covert .wav file,and saw some demo project which shows error